# Kinect for Xbox: SDK selection

Tags: kinect

My application is basically about sound source localization and visual servoing. I selected Kinect as the main hardware.

I already know the basic differences between Kinect for *Windows* and Kinect for *Xbox*. I cannot access to windows version from my country (no reseller here in Turkey), but the xbox version is there at the stores. I am not sure about problem specific software selection.

I found out that the latest Kinect SDK supports sound source localization (and beamforming) using the built-in microphone array. **Can I use that SDK within the xbox version? Or is there another SDK for xbox, having the same support?** I am not sure because I also read that OpenNI does not provide the best audio API.

I will also apply some processing on image & depth outputs, so I will be using OpenCV. I also want to use Qt for threading, GUI etc. So, another question: **Is it possible to use the microsoft official kinect SDK within another IDE, not Visual Studio?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use all versions of the Kinect for Windows SDK, even with an Xbox-version. Some parts are limited and you require a Kinect for Windows in commercial scenarios (more information on [my blog](http://www.kinectingforwindows.com/2012/09/07/what-is-the-difference-between-kinect-for-windows-kinect-for-xbox360/)).

In your scenario you should be able to use the official **Kinect for Windows SDK v1.8** to use the speech/sound scenario. If you are going to do speech/voice recognition, in [this post](http://www.kinectingforwindows.com/2013/12/01/kinecting-ar-drone-pt-i-basic-ui-kinect-camera-voice-recognition/) I set up a basic version to controll my drone which should be the same.

You don't need to use VIsual Studio but C#/C++/VB.net require a compiler to run the code.

**CONCLUSION -** The official SDK will fit your needs, incl. support for speech/voice, but if you want to deploy the application in public you'll need the Kinect for Windows sensor for the public license.

*More questions? --> hello[at]kinectingforwindows[dot]com*

Comment: Thanks, Tom. I will be using C++ / msvc10 compiler on another IDE. Application is not commercial, it is academic. I don't need any extra K4W features. I downloaded v1.8 SDK and used it with success.

Answer (score 0):

There is some discussion about this on stackoverflow. Please check out this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936272/using-xbox-360-kinect-with-kinect-for-windows-sdk

Comment: It is not clear enough. One of the guys say that you cannot use latest SDK with it, but beta version (even you are a hobbyist); whereas other one says kinect sdk 1.5 works. I am starting to think that Microsoft giving out those statements on purpose to make customers buy Windows version.

Comment: if I remember correctly people have used the XBox Kinect and created SDK for it, which is open source. I think that is still available, you can google for it. After that Microsoft released the Microsoft Kinect.